# Disable auto copying of selected text in NetBeans

Tags: netbeans

I'm using NetBeans on Ubuntu. When I select text, it's automatically copied to the clipboard. How can I disable this?

Comment: Why disable ? Security issue or comfort related ?

Comment: Its for comfort

Comment: Content get pasted when you press *Middle button* of your mouse. So avoid accidentally pressing Middle button. If you are using laptop pressing *Button 1 +Button 2* = *Middle button*

Answer (score 3):

The issue is not related to netbeans, but to the way that the X Server handles the clipboard.
In fact X has many clipboards available (they are called `selection`); as soon as you select some data it gets copied to the selection named `PRIMARY` which is different `CLIPBOARD`, the latter is the selection that is used when you do the usual <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> thing.
I'm not aware of any way to disable this behaviour (though I'd be happy do be proven wrong).

See the relevant [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_selection#Clipboard) for details

Answer (score 0):

To disable this feature you may need to edit the `X` window manger to disable loading text to *PRIMARY* and it cost a lots of time & energy.

Content get pasted from *PRIMARY* when you press *Middle button* of your mouse. So the best way is to avoid accidentally pressing Middle button. If you are using laptop pressing *Button 1 +Button 2* = *Middle button*

Let's do a dirty trick.
Open a terminal and run following command

```
while :; do echo -n '' | xclip -selection primary -i ; sleep 0.3; done
```

Remember this will also disable selection of text